# bashrc alias using ticks and backticks not working

Tags: bash, awk, sed, alias

I would like to create in .bashrc an alias which executes the following:

```
virsh list --all | sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'| awk '{print $2" state:"$3" "$4}'
```

I've tried in different ways but nothing works.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What "different ways" exactly have you tried? Those are just single quotes - what's the alias you try to create that uses backtics?

Comment: The bash IRC channel's [factoid on aliases](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias) says "if you have to ask, use a function instead". Wise words, those.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. I had to change an alias to a function just a few days ago because I wanted it to use a parameter if one were present... and OP seems to have more $ than are good for him :-)

Answer (score 5):

This command does not seem to be the normal use case of an alias.

You should instead use a function:

```bash
_virsh() { virsh list --all | sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'| awk '{print $2" state:"$3" "$4}';  }
```

or to avoid the use of `sed`:

```bash
_virsh() { virsh list --all | awk 'NR>2 && $0!="" {print $2" state:"$3" "$4}';  }
```

Put it in your `.bashrc`, restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`, then you can use `_virsh` to get your list.

Comment: an alternative to `$0!=""` is `NF > 0` -- it's not precisely the same, using NF is like `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d'`